# Not seeing sting "NULL" values go into Snowflake stored procedure from python connector

Tags: python, reactjs, express, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, fastapi

I have a FAST API app that is connecting to snowflake via sqlalchemy session maker. The route is pointing to a dynamic stored procedure where the front-end react JS passes in data to express sever via a form which then passes data to fastapi.

What is happening is that if I dont pass in a value in the form then in snowflake that value is being passed in as a " " value inside my stored procedure. I need it to pass a NULL and not an empty string.

My current setup: my fast API endpoint is using the provided data to fill in a stored procedure and then executing the stored procedure and returning the results to the express server then to a react frontend table.

When a user doesn't provide a form field item the data gets passed in as None to my fast api. I wrote a function that checks to see if there is a value and if there is NO VALUE then convert that value to a string "NULL"

This is logic for that process: value = is coming from a pydantic checker

```
value = value if value is not None else "NULL"
```

I then take all the values and construct the stored procedure query.

First a few noteworthy items:

I added `.replace()` values because I found that items weren't containing `' '` around them and `{ }` items were getting placed inside the string value and when NULL was entered it was really entered as 'NULL' all of these scenarios caused syntax errors so having the replace fixed it

The hard coded NULL at position 5 is a value that I don't want to send to the SF so I just leave it as NULL. That NULL is appearing correctly in the final query!

```
stored_procedure= f"CALL {environment}_DB.SCHEMA.PROCNAME(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)" % ({data1},{data2},{data3},{data4},"NULL",{data5},{data6},{data7},{data8})

stored_procedure = stored_procedure.replace('"', "'").replace("{", "").replace("}", "").replace("'NULL'", "NULL") 

results = db.execute(stored_procedure)

## where db = db: Session = Depends(get_db)
```

Using the example where data1 = First Name

```
data1 = "TIM" json is being sent to fast api
```

The stored procedure that's being constructed and being sent to Snowflake is:

```
{environment}_DB.SCHEMA.PROCNAME('TIM','','','',NULL,'','','','')
```

I want/expect this to be passed to snowflake: (No '' values)

```
{environment}_DB.SCHEMA.PROCNAME('TIM',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

The snowflake query is also adding ilike = '' items to each null value! and I'm not sure why.

Any help would be apprenticed thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
It was an issue on the React JS part. In the react-hook-form that I setup I am passing "" values as a default. The reason I have "" was so that on the initial load of the app all the form values are blank. That works for the front end but not so much for the back end.  I needed to convert the "" values to null values before submitting my data to the backend !